# SOAP web service how to change namespace of request

Tags: java, xml, soap, request, namespaces

I have the following xml request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://uciext.ws.hw3/wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:processOrder>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <vendorCode>330029</vendorCode>
            <vendorName>My Shop</vendorName>
            <orderNumber>1000339</orderNumber>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <wsdl:productOrder>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <productSku>111</productSku>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <productName>Kindle Fire</productName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <orderQuantity>5</orderQuantity>
            </wsdl:productOrder>
         </arg0>
      </wsdl:processOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In a class java I recover the productOrder list and elements number is 0.

But if I change the xml to

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://uciext.ws.hw3/wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:processOrder>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <vendorCode>330029</vendorCode>
            <vendorName>My Shop</vendorName>
            <orderNumber>1000339</orderNumber>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <productOrder>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <productSku>111</productSku>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <productName>Kindle Fire</productName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <orderQuantity>5</orderQuantity>
            </productOrder>
         </arg0>
      </wsdl:processOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get 1.

I have the following java class

```
@WebMethod
    OrderConfirm processOrder(@WebParam(name="arg0") Order order
            ) throws Exception;
```

And class ProcessOrder is

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "processOrder", namespace = "http://uciext.ws.hw3/wsdl")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "processOrder", namespace = "http://uciext.ws.hw3/wsdl")
public class ProcessOrder {

    @XmlElement(name = "arg0", namespace = "")
    private com.uciext.ws.hw3.service.model.order.Order arg0;

    public com.uciext.ws.hw3.service.model.order.Order getArg0() {
        return this.arg0;
    }


    public void setArg0(com.uciext.ws.hw3.service.model.order.Order arg0) {
        this.arg0 = arg0;
    }

}
```

How can I remove the wsdl namespace of  or set in java class the namespace to wsdl?